# Xslt generating Html <IMG> tags. How to use an XML node value as an src-attribute for the <IMG> Tags

Tags: html, xslt

I'm still searching, but I haven't found yet the way to perform something like this:

```
xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!-- some other templates -->
    <xsl:template match="IMAGE">
        <img src="src_attribute_to_be_read_from_the_xml_file.jpg"/>
    </xsl:template>     
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In my Xml `<IMAGE>` tags, the text value is the filename that should be inserted in the string `src_attribute_to_be_read_from_the_xml_file.jpg` when processed by this Xslt file.

Have you any idea to perform this ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You use `xsl:attribute`:

```
<img>
    <xsl:attribute name="src">
        <xsl:value-of select="you path here"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

It should also be possible to use

```
<img src="{some expression here}" />
```

According to the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123/#dt-attribute-value-template) this is called a *attribute value template* and should always work (i.e. both XSLT 1.0 and 2.0). Nice. Now I learned something too.

Comment: thx xsl:attribute does the job. and thx for the info about "{$some-variable-here}", I should check to know the way it works.

Comment: It should. I revised my answer.

Comment: @musikk and @Stephane Rolland: Whenever you can use literal result elements and AVT, use it. It's fast and compact.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can use XSL template:

```
<xsl:template match="image">
<xsl:element name="IMG">
  <xsl:attribute name="src">
    <xsl:value-of select="your_path"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="title">
    <xsl:value-of select="your_title"/>
   </xsl:attribute >
</xsl:element>
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you want to add the `height`, `width`, and `alt` attributes, then you can do it like the following:

```
         <img>
             <xsl:attribute name="src">
                 <xsl:value-of select="picture"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="title">
                 <xsl:value-of select="pictureTitle"/>
              </xsl:attribute >
              <xsl:attribute name="alt">
                 <xsl:value-of select="pictureTitle"/>
              </xsl:attribute >
              <xsl:attribute name="height">
                 20
              </xsl:attribute >
              <xsl:attribute name="width">
                 30
              </xsl:attribute >
         </img>
```